# (Laravel) How to pull data from API Controller so that it will display in vue-chartjs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller, chart.js, vue-chartjs

How can i pull the `$mortality` from API/ReportController.php so that i  can use it as chartdata.

ReportController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $mortality = Mortality::select('number_of_mortality')
                            ->where('cycle_id' = 1 )
                            ->get()
}
```

I read the https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data but i dont know how to start. Can you please explain to me in simple way so that i can understand ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index()
{
    $mortality = Mortality::where('cycle_id', 1)->pluck('number_of_mortality');

    return response()->json($mortality);

}
```

In vue, https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data do necessary things as in this link in your view & set the route to your index function here & do console.log(userlist) just below the call for debugging.

```
 try {
        const { userlist } = await fetch('route to your index()')
        console.log(userlist) 
        this.chartData = userlist
        this.loaded = true
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
```

Try this whole example https://appdividend.com/2018/02/23/laravel-vue-js-chartjs-tutorial-example/

Comment: in `Chart.vue`, i'll just copy it?

Comment: No, the data  should be formatted, above code is a basic example. You need to format the JSON data to fit on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This:

```
public function index()
{
    $builder = new Mortality;
    $mortality = $builder->where('cycle_id',1)
                        ->pluck('number_of_mortality');
}
```

Comment: what will be the code for `chart.vue` and `chartContainer.vue`